# Neural Networks: Calculating error with unknown correct answer

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation, reinforcement-learning

If this has been answered else ware, please point me there. I have no doubt that this is a common question but I cannot find an answer.

Let's say I have a Neural Network with multiple outputs and no absolutely-known answer (such as which buttons to press when turning a car on a race track). I also have a single decision and a single result to base my adjustment on. **What maths should I employ to properly calculate error for each output node?** Is it simply [ actual - prediction ] and propagate back, all for each output node?

Also, in the case where not all outputs are used, should I update all of them or just the effective ones? In the car example, say I pressed left and boost and this was a bad answer would I also update right, break, up and down as positives?